# Understanding appropriate image sizes (in pixels) for assets in LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx, assets, image-size

I am creating my first game in LibGDX for android and I will be using an AssetManager to load all of my textures as the game loads up.

I will have a lot of different Images that I will be creating in Illustrator and am uncertain of what is an acceptable maximum size to make them. for example I may have several textures that I wish to cover the entire width of the phone screen with and I do not want them to appear stretched and pixellated. But if I create these images at 1024 width (to allow for a large screen) then wont I be using an unacceptably large amount of memory? but if I make them smaller they will appear stretched and not sharp.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: which devices and screen resolutions do you plan on targeting?

Answer (score 0):

You choose a resolution for your game and make your assets for that resolution.
Then you use a Viewport to make your game fit the resolution of the device.

Link:
[libgdx wiki on Viewports](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports)

Comment: So if I were targeting the galaxy samsung s7 which has a resolution of 1440 x 2560, and I was looking for my images to appear sharp and not stretched i would have to design my images to this criteria? this sounds very large though!

Comment: That is how a digital display works. More pixels means more data. More data means more memory required. 
If you cannot live with your images being upscaled you will have to make them for your highest targeted resolution.
You can not upscale assets without some form of stretching. Computers are not magic. :)